# Configuring "Follow Authorization header" in Webservice connector

Tags: web-services, connector, sailpoint

I am working on rest Webservice connector where in the i.e. URL1 for connectivity redirects to another dynamic i.e. URL2 which might get changed over a time.

I could test the connectivity from postman with additional settings called "Follow Authorization header" to true which allows the header to be passed when received redirect response.

I wanted to know is there similar configuration we can do for Webservice connector? May be in headers etc

Answer (score 0):

I get passed this issue by passing additional header that I need to pass to complete the request. I got handle on it with the additional documentation provided by vendor.